# Intersection of Two Polyhedrons Linear Programming

Tags: convex-optimization, linear-programming, polyhedra

I am stuck on the following linear programming problem:

If P and Q are two n-dimensional polyhedra

Devise a linear programme such that:

If P ∩ Q is nonempty, return a point in P ∩ Q
Else: LP is infeasible.

I might be trivializing the problem but wouldn't the LP:

min (or) max x  such that x is contained in P and Q (the feasible region will be defined by the polyhedron P and Q) work?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

"*min (or) max x such that x is contained in P and Q (the feasible region will be defined by the polyhedron P and Q) work?*" : yes, this is what you want. Can you write this in mathematical terms ?

Let $P = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n\;|\;Ax=b\}$ and $Q = \{x\in \mathbb{R}^n\;|\;Cx=d\}$. $P \cap Q$ is non empty if the system of equations
$$
\left\{
    \begin{array}{ll}
       Ax=b\\
Cx=d\\
x\in \mathbb{R}^n
    \end{array}
\right.
$$
has a solution. As you suggested, you can maximize or minimize any dummy function over this domain to find a feasible solution.